# std::strtoul equivalent in C++ standard library?

Tags: c++

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
    std::string s = "03A0";
    wchar_t wstr = std::strtoul(s.c_str(), nullptr, 16);
    std::wcout << wstr;
}
```

This outputs `Π` on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=728553bb351ea13ffa80af67b193011f-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

**Question**

[`std::strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul), is from `<cstdlib>`. I'm perfectly fine with using it, but I was wondering if the above example was possible using only the C++ standard library (perhaps stringstreams)?

Note also that there is no prefex `0x` on the string indicating hexadecimal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, [`std::stoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul):

```
wchar_t wstr = std::stoul(s, nullptr, 16);
```

The main difference is the fact that it can throw exceptions for errors.

Comment: Ah, doh, I completely forgot about those. And it looks like [MSVC2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404871.aspx) supports them, so great.

Comment: @JesseGood, Yup, though be careful with the reverse as there was a point where most `to_string` calls would be ambiguous.